# How to retrieve value from checkbox defined in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have created a menu with three options(home,change password and logout). In home I am displaying all the books stored in the database. Now I want to filter the contents based on categories of the books using checkbox. By default all the books are shown upon filtering the category only the books of that category should be shown.But for me it is showing all the books even after clicking on all the checkbox (checkbox contains the categories).I think there is some problem in my template file.

urls.py,

```
 url(r'^welcome_user/$',views.welcome_user, name='welcome_user'),
```

Models.py,

```
class Add_cat(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField("Name",max_length=25,unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.category)

class Add_prod(models.Model):
    book = models.CharField("Book Name",max_length=40)
    author = models.CharField("Author",max_length=30)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField("Price")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True)
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Add_cat,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Template file,

```
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
    <div class="sideNav">
        <form action="{% url 'welcome_user' %}">
            <p id=id3>Categories</p>
            <hr>
            {% for i in products %}
                <input type="checkbox" name="cat_name" value="{{i.cat}}">{{i.cat}}<br>
            {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        {% for i in products %}
            <div style="display:inline-block;margin:30px">
                <img src="{{i.image.url}}" alt="No Image" width=196px height=196px>
                <p id=id4>Rs.{{i.price}}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
</body> 
{% endblock %}
```

Views.py,

```
@login_required   
def welcome_user(request):      
    if 'cat_name' in request.GET:
       filter_category = request.GET.getlist('cat_name')
       my_products = Add_prod.objects.filter(cat__in=filter_category) 
       context = { "products":my_products}
    else:
       my_products = Add_prod.objects.all()     
       context = { "products":my_products}
return render(request,"welcome-user.html",context)
```

Answer (score 3):

To check whether checbox value is in sent form you should go with following condition

```
    if 'cat_name' in request.GET:
        #checkbox has been checked
    else:
        #it is not checked
```

Remember that `in` operator return `boolean` so you can also do

```
    filter_category = 'cat_name' in request.GET
```

To get value you just need to get values of 'cat_name' key like:

```
    value = request.GET['cat_name']
```

after checking whether it is in GET parameters or not

Comment: Hey template is being called only on clicking on home menu.When I click on any category template is not being called

Comment: How you are doing filter then? are you using any js function for that? You have to do some action for doing this filter. Either you can do this filter using js code based on check box selection or you have to call back-end service for getting filtered response.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is add `__in` to your filter:

```
@login_required   
def welcome_user(request):      
    filter_category = request.GET.getlist('cat_name')
    categories = Add_cat.objects.all()
    if filter_category: # I couldn’t decipher the structure of an `Add_cat`, so I left off the `in` check since it would not work for lists
        print filter_category
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.filter(cat__in=filter_category) # the template implies that this field is `cat` and not `category`
        context = { "products":my_products}
    else:
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.all()
        context = { "products":my_products}
    return render(request,"welcome-user.html",context)
```

Comment: Hey template is being called only on clicking on home menu.When I click on any category checkbox, template is not being called

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes work a little bit different from other form inputs, so if you examine a post sent from a form that includes a checkbox,

if the checkbox is checked, your queryset will look like:
the value will be 'on'

So, you have to check

```
 if request.POST.get('cb1')=='on': 
        "item is selected"
    else:
        "item is not selected"
```

Comment: After checkbox field I included button submit field like this, <button type="submit">Submit</button>   now I am getting 404 error like this,    http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome_user/%20method%3D?cat_name=Economics

Comment: I have included my urls file in the question.Should I make any changes in the url?

Comment: add method = post in form , and {% csrf_token %} inside the form content then it will directly post data in to your views

Comment: csrf is already there the problem is once I click on submit button after checking in checkbox, it is giving 404 error for my url

Comment: check your apps urls or main urls.py

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code
**Add_prod.objects.filter(cat__in=filter_category)**

```
@login_required   
def welcome_user(request):      
    filter_category = request.GET.getlist('cat_name')

    if filter_category:

        my_products = Add_prod.objects.filter(cat__in=filter_category)
        context = { "products":my_products}
    else:
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.all()
        context = { "products":my_products}
    return render(request,"welcome-user.html",context)
```

*Template file*
Remove quotes(') from {% url 'welcome_user' %}

```
<form method='get' action="{% url welcome_user %}">
```

**UPDATE**

Add quotes between *views.welcome_user*

urls.py

```
url(r'^welcome_user/$','views.welcome_user', name='welcome_user'),
```

Comment: I added button type="submit" after checkbox field.I thought now it will look for action but I am getting page not found for my url. http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome_user/%20method%3D?cat_name=Economics

Comment: URL looks wrong. "welcome_user/%20method%3D?cat_name=Economics"It should be "welcome_user/?cat_name=Economics"

Comment: Replace "<button type="submit">Submit</button>" with <input type="submit">Submit</input>  and <form action="{% url welcome_user %}">

Comment: Page not found Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome_user/%20method%3D?cat_name=Economics

Comment: Economics is a checkbox which i clicked and pressed submit

Comment: Check updated answer. add <form action="{% url welcome_user %}">

Comment: If remove quotes I am getting error like this: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' with arguments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111861/discussion-between-anoop-and-bhanukiran).

Comment: <form method='get' action='{% url welcome_user %}' - this should work. check your code once again

Comment: Your url config is wrong.  views.welcome_user should be with in quotes url(r'^welcome_user/$','views.welcome_user', name='welcome_user'),